# Multiple Axios GET request to get all orders of the month

Tags: javascript, vue.js, woocommerce, axios

I am developing Order Management in Vue for our Woocommerce store. I am trying to fetch all orders of the month through Woocommerce REST API. Problem is default highest retrieval is limited 100 records in API. But I need to retrieve all the orders and display in to a HTML Table as i need to convert the table into a PDF for Taxation.

What I am trying to do is to make multiple requests through "offset" parameter and Axios to get the 100 orders in one attempt.
But each time the array is getting updated with last retrieved records or throwing "Bad request".
How I can archive this to get all orders in one page and in HTML Table?
Below is my Vue code...

```js
methods: {
    // Extract refresh logic into a method
  refreshData () {
    var today= new Date();
    var today1 = new Date(today.getYear(), today.getMonth(), 1);
    today1.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);
    var isoConvert = today1.toISOString();
    console.log(isoConvert);
   
    axios.get('https://stagingSite/wp-json/wc/v3/orders?per_page=100&consumer_key=123&consumer_secret=456', {
        params: {
            after: isoConvert
        }
    })
    .then(response => {
     this.orders = response.data;
      console.log(response);
     })
     .catch(error => {
     console.log(error);
      
    });
     axios.get('https://stagingSite/wp-json/wc/v3/orders?per_page=100&offset=101consumer_key=123&consumer_secret=456', {
        params: {
            after: isoConvert
        }
    })
    .then(response => {
     this.orders = response.data;
      console.log(response);
     })
     .catch(error => {
     console.log(error);
      
    });
  },
```

Comment: Remember that `java` is not `javascript`. They are two completely different languages.

Comment: I don't know how looks the API response you are using, but maybe has something like maximum or total pages. You can create a `while`/`for` loop to obtain all entries and store them on a JS array, after that, just use the data.

Comment: Don't use `this.orders = response.data` that will overwrite the previous results. You can use, for example, `this.orders.push(response.data)` to add new entries to the list.

Comment: You can take a look here: https://blog.kevinchisholm.com/arrays-javascript/javascript-array-management-with-push-pop-shift-and-unshift

Comment: @Nurio Fernández. Thanks for the suggestions and answer. Yes, I am displaying API response to HTML Table , because i need to convert the table to PDF Report at each month's end for taxation. so obviously pagination won't work on this purpose, i Hope.

Comment: Also one more thing is, i am not gonna know how many orders we gonna get for a month, so I am confused that how many requests that i need to make on this...